# Вопрос по пунктуации в официальном письме

Tags: запятые, вводные-слова

Есть вопрос по пунктуации в официальном письме. Один коллега написал предложение без знаков препинания, а второй использовал вводную конструкцию (по его мнению добавил интонацию), обособив ее запятыми:

1. По итогам конкурентной процедуры закупки на право заключения договора поставки оборудования решением тендерного комитета был объявлен победитель.
2. По итогам конкурентной процедуры закупки, на право заключения договора поставки оборудования, решением тендерного комитета был объявлен победитель.

Является ли второй вариант правильным в принципе?

Answer (score 1):

Не является. Там нет вводной конструкции (для неё требуются определённые слова), вводные обязательно обособляются, а не по желанию, как у вас. Обособление там вообще не подходит.

Как можно разделять "*победитель на право заключения договора*"?
Упрощённое предложение:
*На право заключения договора(,) был объявлен победитель.*
Каким боком там запятая? Там же указано, в чём он победил.

Или у вас там уточнение и *закупка на право* (а не *победитель на право*)?
*По итогам конкурентной процедуры закупки, а именно на право заключения договора поставки оборудования...*
Такие уточнения не используются в деловом стиле (стилистическая ошибка), это художественное (примеры в § 53, п. 2, о котором сказано в другом ответе, относятся туда же).

Comment: Это очень грубое, искажающее упрощение, так как в предложении не разделяется дополнение и сказуемое, а обособляются члены между дополнением и сказуемым, что имеет огромную разницу.  Все претензии к Лопатину, так как это он написал, что такие несогласованные определения обособляются факультативно. Это не происходит в деловом стиле речи? В деловом стиле речи люди не обособляют члены предложения паузами для придания речи выразительности? Как раз наоборот, в официальных документах и речах делают это почти всегда, в отличии от художественной литературы.

Comment: Нет, там "победитель на право", это сочетание используется в деловом стиле. Нет в деловом стиле места выразительности за счёт обособления, вы заблуждаетесь, это даже в школе учат, вам лишь бы оправдаться.

Comment: В деловом стиле отсутствует эмоционально окрашенная и иностилевая (разговорная, просторечная) лексика, так как документы, составляющиеся в соответствии с требованиями этого стиля, практически лишены экспрессивности, в них **не используются изобразительно-выразительные средства языка**. https://myfilology.ru/145/osobennosti-funktsionalnykh-stilei-russkogo-iazyka/ofitsialno-delovoi-stil-rechi/

Comment: *в официальных документах и речах* — речь не из той оперы, там есть художественность.

Comment: Здесь написано ‟эмоционально окрашенная и просторечная лексика”. Люди не высказывают эмоциональных оценок и не называют друг друга ‟чуваками”. Причем здесь выразительные паузы?

Comment: Вы читать умеете? **В них [документах] не используются изобразительно-выразительные средства языка.** Вообще не используются, любые средства (и пунктуационные в том числе), нет речи о каких-то конкретных. Это очень известный факт, это проходят в школах. Давайте примеры, а вы их не найдёте, потому что они не существуют.

Comment: Изобразительно-выразительные средства — это различные фигуральные приемы, вроде метафор. Конечно никто не станет использовать метафоры в деловом стиле!

Comment: Теперь к словам придираетесь. А наше как назвать? Пунктуационно-выразительные средства? Не стоит так выкручиваться. Не думаю, что вы изучали деловой стиль в учебных заведениях, совсем не похоже на то. Я — да.

Comment: Если речь идет о деловом документе не технического характера (как здесь), то вы вполне можете поставить запятые, которые обозначают выразительные паузы. Мое мнение, что тут нет какой-либо ошибки. Это просто принципиальное расхождение. Я считаю, что вот в такой документе можно поставить выразительные паузы, а вы — нет. Пожалуйста, можете продолжать так считать.

Comment: К тому же из-за значительной распространенности несогласованного определения обособление не просто придаст выразительности данному предложению, но и облегчит его восприятие. Скорее всего, данными соображениями и руководствовался коллега человека, который задал данный вопрос.

Comment: Подумаешь, стилистическая ошибка, не пунктуационная, не так страшно. В деловом стиле принято **сообщать всё сразу**, а не добавлять данные через уточнение, в котором подходит "а именно". В деловом стиле не принято выделять важное запятыми, это исключительно художественное. Справочники Розенталя и Лопатина основаны на примерах из классической литературы, особенностей делового стиля там нет. "На право" можно заменить на "касательно". И там обособите? Значительной распространенность — особенность стиля. Шесть слов — не критично, без обособления читается нормально.

Comment: Стили это просто очень общая классификация, а в реальности стили в различных ситуациях могут переплетаться. Деловая речь в реальном мире и ситуации может приобретать элементы художественного стиля , как и наоборот. Чтобы сказать, что что-то является стилистической ошибкой, нужно разбирать конкретную ситуацию, так как только так можно судить об уместности тех или иных слов, фигуральных приемов, пауз, знаков препинания.

Comment: Деловой стиль очень строгий, остальные — да, переплетаются. Ну так мы и разбираем конкретную ситуацию. Одна из черт делового стиля — точность, поэтому уточнения (неточного) неуместны.

Comment: Ну вы что... Запятые здесь даже в _самой художественной_ литературе в виде авторского знака неприемлемы, так как они разбивают целую конструкцию: "процедура закупки на право...". Если такие запятые разрешать как авторские, то будет анархия и хаос, _народ, будет, запятые, ставить, после, каждого, слова_ и говорить "я так слышу".

Answer (score -1):

Это не вставная конструкция, а распространенное несогласованное определение. В справочниках есть [вот такой раздел](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=119#pp119), где в параграфе 53, пункте 2, сказано, что обособление подобных несогласованных определений факультативно. Насколько я понимаю, факультативное обособление это двоякое произношение, встречающееся в речи. Так что да, при обособлении запятыми данное несогласованное определение произносится с короткими паузами по краям, как отступление.
Но допустимы оба варианта — с запятыми и без.